# PostgreSQL connect to the same session from two differnet applications

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql database for a Qt application that uses some database session parameters.
I need to connect to the database using another application -may be BIRT report or a php application or other - but using the same session as the first Qt application.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two connects to one session are not possible. One session can to handle only one connect. There is a possibility to share snapshot between transactions. This feature is used by some PostgreSQL applications like `pg_dump` for implementation `-j` option. The sharing snapshot isn't sharing sessions - there are some limits about visibility of changes and this feature is really rare used.

See the [related doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-SNAPSHOT-SYNCHRONIZATION) or [article](http://www.depesz.com/2013/03/05/parallel-dumping-of-databases/) about this feature.

```
-- first session
BEGIN;
SELECT pg_export_snapshot(); -- returns 00000AAF-1

-- second session
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT '00000AAF-1';
```

Next the initial visible content will be same for both session. **But first session doesn't see any new activity of second session and vice versa.**

Comment: Thank you very much. That would be suitable. I need the second session for reporting purposes only and it will not affect data.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. In PostgreSQL sessions are stricly associate with connection to the server therefore session and connetion are really a synonymous terms.
When you connect to the server by any channel (TCP, local) the postmaster process is forked creating your session's child process to which your client application is “talking” and running transactions. When you disconnect the child process is terminated and session ends.

Maybe tell as more about your requirements? 
[Pavel Stehule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406691/pavel-stehule) [propose you an interesting feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33067579/5404196). But it's really an advanced stuff and probably it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that [Pavel Stehule](http://stackoverflow.com/users/406691/pavel-stehule) has sugessted good solution.