# Is it possible to add queries to existing transactions in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

This is to work out a distributed transaction issue in micro service structure.

For example, in an e-commerce application with micro service architecture, it uses one postgres db for all services. When order service has received one rest request to create a new order, order service will talk to many other services, such as coupon service, payment service, etc. Ideally, these external services (out of order service) will use the same db transaction to create records in their own service scope. Something like:

```
// service order create a new order
func create() {
    tx := db.Begin() // start a new transaction
    defer tx.Rollback()

    tx.CreateOrder()
    tx.CreateOrderItem()

    err = service.Coupon().CreateOrderCoupon()
    err = service.Payment().CreateOrderPayment()

    tx.Commit()
}
```

It's not possible to pass `tx` out of order service like

```
// service order create a new order
func create() {
    tx := db.Begin() // start a new transaction
    defer tx.Rollback()

    tx.CreateOrder()
    tx.CreateOrderItem()

    err = service.Coupon().CreateOrderCoupon(tx) // pass tx as argument to external service
    err = service.Payment().CreateOrderPayment(tx) // pass tx as argument to external service

    tx.Commit()
}
```

Service coupon/payment may run in separate machine in cloud, and communicating with other services is done by grpc.

I'm thinking of something like this

```
// service order create a new order
func create() {
    tx := db.Begin() // start a new transaction
    defer tx.Rollback()

    txID := tx.ID()

    tx.CreateOrder()
    tx.CreateOrderItem()
 
    // pass the transaction id to external service
    err = service.Coupon().CreateOrderCoupon(txID)
    err = service.Payment().CreateOrderPayment(txID)

    tx.Commit()
}

// service coupon creates order coupon
func CreateOrderCoupon(txID) {
    // coupon service get the transaction id, and create coupon record within the passed transaction.
    tx := db.BeginWithTXID(txID)

    tx.CreateCoupon()

    return nil
}
```

This is to add an extra layer to the db driver. Every sql needs to check whether this sql belongs to an existing transaction, or should it start a brand new transaction before this sql query is sent to db server.

I know some company is doing something similar with mysql. Not sure if it's possible with Postgres.

Comment: If you want your micro-services to all share the same db transaction then you don't want micro-services do you? The whole point is that they are independent.

Comment: In one sense, that's correct. On the other hand, assuming the micro-services are not using one same db transaction, and they are using 2pc or 3pc to achieve the distributed transaction, they are still kind of dependent on each other. One service failed, then all other services should rollback. In this case of one database for all services, it seems to me one same db transaction could save much effort for 2pc or 3pc implementation, providing one db transaction works ^

Comment: This is commonly implemented at a higher layer for these kinds of multi-step operations. They store their own kind of transaction IDs in a regular table in the DB and scrap the operation if one step fails, or possibly retry that step. That requires more manual effort but is also a lot more flexible. For example, chances are one of these steps also requires interacting with an external service for longer than you want to leave your DB xact open for. Those connections are limited resources, and in serializable mode, the xact will fail often if left open long.

Comment: There usually will be a timeout for such transaction if it's implemented like this.

Comment: Of course, but I can see a multi-part e-commerce transaction taking a total of 1-10 seconds in non-error/timeout scenarios. Holding transactions open that long, your DB will quickly become a bottleneck that you can't easily scale out. For instance, a $400/mo Heroku Postgres DB gives you 500 connections, and you don't get more by paying more (up to $16K/mo). If the operations are quick enough that it doesn't matter, I don't see why these would be separate services sharing a DB instead of just one service.

Comment: Usually, the timeout will be controlled under 1 second. If one action can be achieved through eventual consistency, such as sending message, then this action doesn't have to go through this center transaction. It can be done through a MQ message.

Answer (score 1):

I've read a lot of the Postgres docs and never come across such a feature, including in the `SET TRANSACTION` commands, so I don't think so. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066372/postgresql-connect-to-the-same-session-from-two-differnet-applications) suggests the same. I don't see why this couldn't work in theory, since it could be done with a central session proxy where each service gives it a token to execute commands in the respective transaction. Whether or not this would be a good design is a separate discussion.

Comment: thanks sudo! I will look after this and see how to implement it.